# Migrate data from azure mongodb to azure search

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Microsodt azure cloud provider in my project,where i have a mongodb installed on a VM on azure and also I have azure cognitive search instance . what I want to do is to migrate the data which i have on mongodb to azure search in order to create indexes and then use the restful apis on the client application.
my question is, is there a way to move data from mongodb to azure search please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a built in Mongo DB connector for Azure Search as of now. However you have two options.

Migrate from Mongodb to Azure Cosmos DB (Mongo API) and then create an Azure Search Indexer for the Azure Cosmos DB in question, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-mongodb-cosmos-db-online

Write a custom code application that pulls data from Mongo and then send it to Azure Search indexes, you can do this by using the push API, take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-optimize-indexing-push-api

Comment: thanks for you answer I will go for the second option, we can you javascript ?

Comment: yep, we do have client libraries for JS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/search-documents-readme?view=azure-node-latest

Comment: I have another challenge if you could help please.
imagine I migrate the data on Azure search, how can I detect if any new records are inserted on mongodb or modified, because i need to update the azure search too, do you have any idea please ?

Comment: @Javascriptuser if you go with second option then you can use `created_date` or `updated_date` in where condition when getting data from mongodb so you will get only data created after specific time. You can maintain file which will store last crawl timestamp and schdule cusom code application to get data from mongodb periodically.

Comment: thanks for you answer, image I have some APIs which are triggered every time on the front-end when a new record inserted or changed(the purpose of these APIs is to update the azure search), is there a way to delete/update the records on Azure search ? can you provide some docs to do that please? thanks a lot for your time

Comment: These are the available methods in the Searclient for JS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/search-documents/searchclient?view=azure-node-latest#methods
There you will see the deletedocument and mergedocument ones